# How to modify get_text function of BeautifulSoup according to required formatting?

Tags: html, text, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, strsplit

I want to scrape [this](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656) webpage. I'm using BeautifulSoup.

```
url="https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656" 
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
block_details=soup.find(class_="hnfgic-0 jlMXIC")
print block_details.get_text()
```

The output is:

```
Hash00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656Confirmations8Timestamp2019-11-21 17:52Height604806MinerSlushPoolNumber of Transactions2,003Difficulty12,973,235,968,799.78Merkle root49ee8cb431ef3e613fdc9ac3146335d1a608a0e6afb5cf9ab44c9ddc51acfbe9Version0x20000000Bits387,297,854Weight3,993,364 WUSize1,355,728 bytesNonce849,455,972Transaction Volume4560.73542334 BTCBlock Reward12.50000000 BTCFee Reward0.19346486 BTC
```

But i want the output as:

```
Hash
00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656
Confirmations
8
Timestamp
2019-11-21 17:52
Height
604806
.
.
.
```

I intend to use `strsplit` function with this string. So a end-line separator between two texts will help me differentiate the strings by using `strsplit("\n")`.
Please help.

EDIT:  Selenium's `.text` function generates my desired output, but I want a fix using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `separator='\n'` parameter to `get_text()` method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
block_details=soup.find(class_="hnfgic-0 jlMXIC")
print(block_details.get_text(separator='\n'))  # <-- note the separator parameter
```

Prints:

```
Hash
00000000000000000011898368c395f1c35d56ea9109d439256d935a4fe7d656
Confirmations
13
Timestamp
2019-11-21 17:52
Height
604806
Miner
SlushPool
Number of Transactions
2,003
Difficulty
12,973,235,968,799.78
Merkle root
49ee8cb431ef3e613fdc9ac3146335d1a608a0e6afb5cf9ab44c9ddc51acfbe9
Version
0x20000000
Bits
387,297,854
Weight
3,993,364 WU
Size
1,355,728 bytes
Nonce
849,455,972
Transaction Volume
4560.73542334 BTC
Block Reward
12.50000000 BTC
Fee Reward
0.19346486 BTC
```